# Creating contour lines using GDAL and Delphi

Tags: delphi, gdal

I am trying to create isolines using Delphi and GDAL18. For that I am using the following code:

```
layer:= OGRCreateLayer( ogr_ds, PAnsiChar(WideStringToString('contour')), nil, ogr.wkbLineString, nil);
err:= GDALContourGenerate(band, 1, 0, 0, aFixedLevel, 0, 0, layer, 0, 1, nil, nil);
```

The GDALContourGenerate command returns an "Unnsupported Geometry Type" - error.

I included the gdal18.dll the following way:

```
function GDALContourGenerate(srcBand: TGDALRasterBandH; contourInterval: double;
                       contourBase: double; fixedLevelCount: longint; fixedLevel: TDoubleArray2;
                       useNoData: longint; noDataValue: double;
                       layer: TOGRLayerH; idField: longint; elevField: longint;
                       pfnProgress: TGDALProgressFunc; pProgressArg : POINTER): TOGRErr; external External_Lib name 'GDALContourGenerate';
```

I've also tried other geometry types (e.g. wkbLineString25D) but this did not help.
I would be glad if you'ld have any suggestions.
Thnaks a lot,
Mario

*[edit]I found out that the same error occurs when I replaye "layer" (in GDALContourGenerate) with "nil". So maybe the problem is somewhere else.[/edit]*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably add `cdecl` after the external declarations, as such (the name matches the function declaration in Delphi, so it can be ignored):

```
function GDALContourGenerate(srcBand: TGDALRasterBandH; contourInterval: double;
                       contourBase: double; fixedLevelCount: longint; fixedLevel: TDoubleArray2;
                       useNoData: longint; noDataValue: double;
                       layer: TOGRLayerH; idField: longint; elevField: longint;
                       pfnProgress: TGDALProgressFunc; pProgressArg : POINTER): TOGRErr; 
cdecl; external External_Lib;
```

Or the `stdcall` word depending how the dll was compiled.

And for the string parameters, since gdal uses `*char` parameters AFAIK in its C flat API, you can use a `PAnsiChar` directly, as such:

```
      layer:= OGRCreateLayer( ogr_ds, 'contour', nil, ogr.wkbLineString, nil);
```

Before Delphi 2009, you can use `pointer(aString)` for such parameters, and since Delphi 2009, just a `pointer(AnsiString(aString))` to typecast a `aString: string` value.

How did you [convert the .h header](http://www.drbob42.com/delphi/headconv.htm)?

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent a long time searching for the problem but I did not see that I forgot "cdecl". Now everything works fine!